# Django query depth search

Tags: sql, django, django-rest-framework, depth-first-search

I have an djangorestframework app where I have data from external source which I cannot affect. There is tier structure with employees and supervisors.

models.py :

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    supervisor = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField(max_length=100)
```

I know this is wrong and the supervisor should be foreign key, but that is not under my controll. What I need is that I get a request for high level supervisor, so the final query will return all employees for the requested supervisor and if some of the employee is also a supervisor then return all his employees till it comes to the lowest level where the employees are not supervisors. It should work like Depth-first search.
Is there any way to return this query?

Comment: Please improve your question. What is your SuperVisor model, what the field supervisor can contain?

Comment: There is no supervisor model. It can contain name of the person.